# Adding an alert after an onSubmit within a function

Tags: reactjs, alert

I am trying to add an alert after I have called onSubmit. As you can see in the function below using I have added the alert but it wont show up after I click my submit button. It works perfectly fine using just the regular 'alert' feature (I have commented it out below) but I want to style/personalize the alert hence why I am wanting to add it in this way. What am I missing? TIA for your help.

```
  function sendEmail(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    emailjs.sendForm('hidden', 'hidden', e.target, 'hidden')
      .then((result) => {
          return(
            <div class="alert">
            <span class="closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span>
            Great, your message has been sent.
          </div>
          )

       
        // alert("Great, your request has been sent!"); 
        
      }, (error) => {
        alert("Oops, something went wrong. Please try again")
      });
      e.target.reset();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot just return jsx from any function from inside your onClick handler . you have to include the code inside your `return ()`  of the component (or render() if you are using class based component) .

#### Alternative approach :

add a state variable to show alert

```
const [alertVisibility , setAlertVisibility ] = useState(false)
```

and inside your onClick

```
.then((result) => {
      setAlertVisibility(true);
}
```

and inside your render function add this.

```
     { 
      alertVisibility && 

      <div class="alert">
        <span class="closebtn" 
        Great, your message has been sent.
      </div>
      }
```

Comment: Thanks so much Mohammed, I wasn't able to solve my issue, as you can see I've added my full code, any help would be appreciated!